# Multiple ID's in database

Tags: sql

I have a database that contains a few tables such as person, staff, member, and supporter.

The person table contains information about every staff, member, and supporter. The information it contains is name,address,email, and telephone. I also created an id that is the primary key.

My issue is that I also have an primary key ID for staff, member, and supporter.

For instance, in the person table is John with id 1.
He is a supporter so in the supporter table is pID(for person id)to reference back to John with all his information and ID(for supporter ID).

pID references to the person table and every person has an ID incremented by 1 starting at 1. supporter ID is for every supporter and also starts at 1 and is incremented by 1.

Is it possible to have in the supporter table pID = 1 and supporter ID = 1? Another person may have a pID = 26 and supporter ID = 5.

Or will supporter ID have to be different than the pID and be something like "sup"? So you would have pID = 1 and supporter ID = sup1 or pID = 26 and supporter ID = sup5

Answer (score 3):

Primary keys are unique only within the context of a table. If a column in one table refers to a primary key in another table then you should set up a foreign key constraint so the references don't accidentally out if sync.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the person ID and supporter ID can be the same number, as long as your code keeps track of which ID type is which.

Comment: "You just need to have distinct column names on each table" - no you don't - it just keeps you from having to specify the table name when doing a query.

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely unclear -- I meant that within each table, you have to have distinct column names.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Key, that's what you are looking for. Your Primary Key in the person table can be referenced by all the other tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE person(personId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), FirstName VARCHAR(50), LastName VARCHAR(50))
    CREATE TABLE staff(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), personId INT  REFERENCES person(personId))
    CREATE TABLE member(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), personId INT  REFERENCES person(personId))
    CREATE TABLE supporter(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), personId INT  REFERENCES person(personId))

    INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Adrian', 'Sullivan'), ('Frank', 'Sullivan'), ('Another', 'Sullivan'),('John', 'Sullivan') 
    SELECT * FROM person

    INSERT INTO staff VALUES (1),(3)
    INSERT INTO member VALUES (2),(3),(4)
    INSERT INTO supporter VALUES (1),(4)

    SELECT 
    person.personId
    , person.FirstName
    , person.LastName
    , staff.id [IsStaff]
    , member.id [IsMember]
    , supporter.id [IsSupporter]
    FROM person
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff ON person.personid = staff.personId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN member ON person.personid = member.personId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN supporter ON person.personid = supporter.personId
```

[image]